# Dropzone JS not passing to PHP $_FILES

Tags: javascript, php, dropzone.js

I am using Dropzone JS to build an image uploader that allows you to upload more than one image at once:

HTML:

```
<div class="dropzone" id="mydroppyzone"><div class="dz-message" data-dz-message><span><i class="fas fa-images"></i> Add Photos</span></div></div>
```

JS:

```
$("#mydroppyzone").dropzone({
    url: "process_edit_event.php",
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    maxFiles: 4,
    maxFilesize: 2,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 100,
    acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png",
    init: function () {

        var myDropzone = this;

        $("#editEventBtn").click(function (e) {

            var editEventFormIsValid = $('#editEventFeaturedForm').valid();

            if (editEventFormIsValid) {

                if (myDropzone.getQueuedFiles().length > 0) {   
                    e.preventDefault();
                    myDropzone.processQueue(); 
                } else {                

                }

            }               

        }); 

      myDropzone.on('success', function (file, response) {

        console.log(JSON.stringify(file.upload.filename));

        var form = document.getElementById('editEventFeaturedForm');

        $("#editEventFeaturedForm").append($('<input type="hidden" ' +
        'name="theFiles[]" ' +
        'value="' + file.upload.filename + '">'));

        form.submit();

      });
   },
   sending: function (file, xhr, formData) {
       formData.append("name", $('#name').val());
   }
});
```

process_edit_event.php

```
// Upload the event photos to the server

    $ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

    $storeFolder = 'user_images/events';

    if (!empty($_FILES)) {

        $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];         

        $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;

        $targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name'];

        foreach($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] as $key => $value) {
            $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key];
            $targetFile =  $targetPath . $_FILES['file']['name'][$key];
            move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
        }

    }
```

When I console log everything on the JavaScript side, the image processes as it should but on the PHP side $_FILES is always empty.

I am stumped trying to figure out why $_FILES is empty. Is there something I'm missing in the JavaScript that isn't passing over into PHP? Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is your `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` set to? You can check your ini config on the server or do a quick `ini_get('upload_max_filesize')`

Comment: @jfadich 64M it says.. the files im testing with are really small too. The image looks to be processing fine on the Dropbox side, it just never seems to make it into $_FILES. This code was working for me originally.. and then suddenly stopped

Comment: Your javascript code adds the file to an input named `theFiles` but your PHP code is trying to read `$_FILES['file']`. Either change your input's name to `file` or check `$_FILES['theFiles']`

Comment: @rickdenhaan thanks I tried both of those but neither worked. Wouldn't $FILES be read as not empty regardless?

Comment: Hmm, yes it should. Assuming your form has its `enctype` set to `multipart/form-data`. Does it?

Comment: @rickdenhaan the dropzone is attached to a div not a form.. is there somewhere else I attach multipart/form-data to in this case?

Comment: `var form = document.getElementById('editEventFeaturedForm')` -- this gets a div? You're calling `form.submit()` -- a div does not have a `submit` method.

Comment: @rickdenhaan no that's the ID of the form itself

Comment: Right. That's where you're appending the input with the file, so *that* form should have its `enctype` set properly.

Comment: Good find! I did that however and still no go :( Doesn't seem like its ever passing over into PHP :(. $_FILES is still empty apparently. Appreciate your continued help and looking into this!

Comment: Ah, wait, hang on. Just noticed something: your input has a `type` of `hidden`. That won't work. The type must be `file`. A hidden input only supports text values, not file objects.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the form is being sent 2 times, because when the file is uploaded, the `upload.php` is automatically executed through ajax.

You must eliminate the submit of the form, because when we click on it, it is already the second time it is executed and therefore, does not find any files to upload.